# Is there a simple way to see the intensity of each point of an image?

Tags: opencv, click, mouse, opencv3.0

I am using threshold on a batch of images (more than one hundred). If I could to see the intensity of each point by clicking the mouse on the gray image, it would be a very fantastic and easy way to find good threshold numbers for all the images. But I am new on OpenCV and don't know how can I do it. May someone guide me or put an existing code if there is one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setMouseCallback` function (see [opencv doc](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga89e7806b0a616f6f1d502bd8c183ad3e)) to set the callback to imshow window which would provide you with coordinates of your click event.

```
void onClickCallback(int event, int x, int y, int, void*);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    Mat image = imread("/home/zda/0.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    namedWindow("image");
    setMouseCallback( "image", onClickCallback, &image);

    imshow("image",image);
    while ('q' != waitKey(0));
}

void onClickCallback( int event, int x, int y, int, void *image) {
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        std::cout << "value at (" << x << ", " << y << ") is " << ((Mat*)image)->at<Vec3b>(y, x) << endl;
        //This one for grayscale
        //std::cout << "value at (" << x << ", " << y << ") is " << (int)((Mat*)image)->at<uchar>(y, x) << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how should I change this line if I want to have intensity of a gray image? `((Mat*)image)->at<Vec3b>(y, x)` .  I tried `((Mat*)image)->at<uchar>(y, x)` but didn't work

Comment: @user8663682 it would be         `std::cout << "value at (" << x << ", " << y << ") is " << (int)((Mat*)image)->at<uchar>(y, x) << endl;`
Note that you will need to convert result to int so that it doesn't print unprintable char instead

Comment: I only want to see the intensity of each pixel of a grayscaled image, when I clicking on it. but this `std::cout << "value at (" << x << ", " << y << ") is " << (int)((Mat*)image)->at<uchar>(y, x) << endl;` gives me assertion failed error.

Comment: Post full version of code which gives you assertion error in your question. Issue is likely somewhere else.